# /usr/bin/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/google-chrome: undefined symbol: gbm_bo_get_modifier

Tags: centos, google-chrome

「symbol lookupエラー」になったのですが、どういう意味ですか？

```
$ google-chrome --version

Google Chrome 79.0.3945.79

$ sudo yum install https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

Downloading packages: (1/2):
vulkan-filesystem-1.1.97.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm                          |
6.3 kB  00:00:00      (2/2): vulkan-1.1.97.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm                                     | 3.6 MB  00:00:00     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 合計                                                               4.0
MB/s | 3.6 MB  00:00:00      Running transaction check Running
transaction test Transaction test succeeded Running transaction  
インストール中          : vulkan-filesystem-1.1.97.0-1.el7.noarch            
1/4    インストール中          : vulkan-1.1.97.0-1.el7.x86_64                
2/4    更新します              :
google-chrome-stable-109.0.5414.119-1.x86_64                       3/4
整理中                  : google-chrome-stable-79.0.3945.79-1.x86_64     
4/4    検証中                  : vulkan-1.1.97.0-1.el7.x86_64            
1/4    検証中                  :
google-chrome-stable-109.0.5414.119-1.x86_64                       2/4
検証中                  : vulkan-filesystem-1.1.97.0-1.el7.noarch        
3/4    検証中                  :
google-chrome-stable-79.0.3945.79-1.x86_64                         4/4
 
 
依存性関連をインストールしました:   vulkan.x86_64 0:1.1.97.0-1.el7            
vulkan-filesystem.noarch 0:1.1.97.0-1.el7            
 
更新:   google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:109.0.5414.119-1                  
 
 
完了しました!

$ google-chrome --version

/usr/bin/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/google-chrome:
undefined symbol: gbm_bo_get_modifier
```

環境
CentOS7

[Error of installing Google Chrome in Centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74810796/error-of-installing-google-chrome-in-centos-7)

---

yum update 後

```
$ yum list installed
//中略
mesa-libEGL.x86_64                          17.0.1-6.20170307.el7               @base              
mesa-libGL.x86_64                           17.0.1-6.20170307.el7               @base              
mesa-libgbm.x86_64                          17.0.1-6.20170307.el7               @base              
mesa-libglapi.x86_64                        17.0.1-6.20170307.el7               @base 
//中略

$ sudo yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
ファイルが開けません:  google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm を飛ばします。
何もしません

$ ll | grep google
$ strings /lib64/libgbm.so.1 | grep gbm_bo_get_modifier
$ rpm -qf /lib64/libgbm.so.1
mesa-libgbm-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"undefined symbol:" はバイナリの実行に必要な共有ライブラリに該当のシンボルが見つからない時に表示されるエラーで、"undefined symbol: gbm_bo_get_modifier" は `libgbm.so.1` に含まれているようです。

例えば以下のように `strings` コマンドを使って確認することができます。

```
$ strings /lib64/libgbm.so.1 | grep gbm_bo_get_modifier
gbm_bo_get_modifier
```

libgbm.so.1 は "mesa-libgbm" パッケージに含まれており、CentOS 7.9-2009 でのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
$ rpm -qf /lib64/libgbm.so.1
mesa-libgbm-18.3.4-12.el7_9.x86_64
```

今回は確認のため CentOS 7 を minimal からインストール、質問と同じく Chrome の rpm ファイルを直接インストールしたところ、特に問題は発生しませんでした。
`yum` の実行時に依存性の解決で mesa-libgbm 等も自動でインストールされました。

---

**提案1:**

mesa-libgbm がインストールされているかを確認し、`yum update` でシステムのパッケージを最新の状態に更新してみてください。

**提案2:**

予め rpm ファイルをダウンロードしておいてからインストールする手順で、`yum localinstall` を使う方法があるようです。下記リンク先の内容が今回の事例に近い気がします。

[rpmをインストールする時に「依存性の欠如」が出た場合は、yum localinstallを使う](https://ruka.app/rpm%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%80%8C%E4%BE%9D%E5%AD%98%E6%80%A7%E3%81%AE%E6%AC%A0%E5%A6%82%E3%80%8D%E3%81%8C%E5%87%BA/)

> ```
> # yum localinstall google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm
> ```

---

**追記**

私が確認した環境は **CentOS 7.9-2009** ですが、質問には CentOS 7 としか書かれていません。"mesa-libgbm-17.0.1-6.20170307.el7.x86_64" は調べてみると恐らく **CentOS 7.4** でのパッケージバージョンです。

共有ライブラリ中に含まれるシンボルはバージョンによって異なりますので、CentOS を最新の状態 (7.9) に更新してください。

Comment: 試してみましたがうまくいきませんでした。本文へ追記しました。

Comment: CentOS 7.9 へアップデートしたら、無事にバージョンが表示されるようになりました。